# Is there a convergence proof for ADMM applied to biconvex/bilinear problems?

Tags: optimization, admm

Ok, I've already asked this question in [math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1257497/144053), but I feel it is more appropriate to ask here (hopefully I am not violating any rules by repeating!). So here it is:

> I wonder if there is a local convergence proof for ADMM applied to biconvex problems? More specifically, my problem is as follows:
>
> $$\min_{x,y} f(x) + g(y) + \| y \circ Ax \|_2^2  $$ ,
>
> where $\circ$ denotes Hadamard product and $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ are convex functions. This fits into biconvex setting mentioned in Boyd's paper on distributed ADMM, but without theoretical evidence.
>
> Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

To partially answer my question - there is [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1410.1390) paper, but coming with a strong assumption on the multiplier value.
Mingyi Hong, Zhi-Quan Luo, Meisam Razaviyayn "Convergence Analysis of Alternating Direction Method of Multipliers for a Family of Nonconvex Problems"

Comment: Please provide the full citation (since links are not usually permanent).